# How to get JSON objects value in dataTables columns initialization, if its name contains dots?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, datatables

I'm using Data Table server side, but i can't get the JSON object.
The table is initialized in this way:

```
var table = $('#index-table-company_tutors').DataTable({
          buttons: buttons,
          serverSide: true,
          order: [[0, 'asc']],
          pageLength: 10,
          ajax: 'company_tutors.json',
          columns: [
            { data: 'company_tutors.name' },
            { data: 'company_tutors.surname' },
            { data: 'company_tutors.phone' },
            { data: 'company.name'}
          ]});
```

I'm using Rails, so in the index controller i get the columns name and then i select it in the database, but in this case i need to join two tables where the attributes have the same name. For this reason I need to use `company_tutors.name` end `company.name`

```
format.json do
        # search[value]:

        # default 10 massimo 50
        limit = [(params[:length] || '10').to_i, 50].min
        # default 0
        offset = params[:start].to_i
        # always include :id column
        columns = (params[:columns]
        .reject { |_, value| value[:data] == '' } # workaround exclude empty column (last one)
        .map { |_, value| value[:data].to_sym } << :id).uniq
        #
        order = (params[:order].map do |_, spec|
          # default :id
          column = spec[:column] ? columns[spec[:column].to_i] : :id
          # default :asc
          dir = spec[:dir] == 'desc' ? :desc : :asc
          [column, dir].join(' ')
        end)
        page = if params[:search][:value].blank?
                 @company_tutors.joins(:farm)
                                .limit(limit).offset(offset)
                                .order(order)
               else
                 @company_tutors.joins(:farm)
                                .search(params[:search][:value])
                                .limit(limit).offset(offset)
                                .order(order)
               end
        @data = page.pluck(*columns).map { |x| Hash[columns.zip(x)] }
      end
```

This is an example of the generated JSON:

```
{"data":[{"company_tutors.name":"Name_test","company_tutors.surname":"Surname_test","company_tutors.phone":"335-7744391","company.name":"Company name","id":18}]}
```

The JSON is well generated, but DataTable give me this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=index-table-company_tutors - Requested
>   unknown parameter 'company_tutors.name' for row 0, column 0. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

I suppose that I have to save the data in a variable and than do something like:

```
var table = $('#index-table-company_tutors').DataTable({
              buttons: buttons,
              serverSide: true,
              order: [[0, 'asc']],
              pageLength: 10,
              ajax: 'company_tutors.json',
              columns: [
                { data: mydata['company_tutors.name'] },
                { data: mydata['company_tutors.surname'] },
                { data: mydata['company_tutors.phone'] },
                { data: mydata['company.name']}
              ]});
```

But I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having dots in your JSON property names, you must use `\\` to escape the dots:

```
columns: [
  { data: 'company_tutors\\.name' },
  { data: 'company_tutors\\.surname' },
  { data: 'company_tutors\\.phone' },
  { data: 'company\\.name'}
]
```

Otherwise dataTables will believe you are refering to a nested object, i.e `{ company_tutors: { name: 'xyz, ... }}`